# Hierarchical conclusion sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table in database with departments list. [image: here you can look at it]

I wrote this piece of code:

```
WITH tree (Id, Name, Level)
AS
(
SELECT t.Id, t.Name, 0 AS Level
FROM DepartmentsT AS t WHERE t.ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT d.Id, d.Name, Level+1
FROM DepartmentsT AS d INNER JOIN tree ON tree.Id = d.ParentId
)

SELECT * FROM tree
```

And I got

[image: this]

So here the question. How can I make records to show "hierarchically", I mean to children were shown under their parents, not the way they are showing right now? Now they are sorted by their nested levels and simple ORDER BY doesn't solve the problem. Hope for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep this information as you traverse the tree:

```
WITH tree (Id, Name, Level, parents) AS (
      SELECT t.Id, t.Name, 0 AS Level,
             cast(t.id as varchar(max)) as parents
      FROM DepartmentsT t
      WHERE t.ParentId IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT d.Id, d.Name, Level+1,
             tree.parents + '-->' + cast(d.id as varchar(max))
      FROM DepartmentsT d INNER JOIN
           tree
           ON tree.Id = d.ParentId
    )
SELECT id, name, level
FROM tree
ORDER BY parents;
```

Note:  This assumes that the ids are all the same length.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just changed ids to parents and it worked!